Python: цвет фона изображения на кнопке, пребывающей в режиме disabled
Есть в форме кнопка tkinter.Button. Ничего необычного в конфигурации нет:
mybutton.configure(background = "blue", disabledforeground = "white", foreground = "white", image = "image.png")

С кнопкой связан длительный процесс. Для того, чтоб не дать пользователю опять нажать на кнопку в процессе, я блокирую её:
mybutton.configure(state = "disabled")

Когда процесс завершается, я её деблокирую:
mybutton.configure(state = "normal")

Мне кажется, что такой путь предотвращения проблем с повторным запуском, выглядит более-менее. Но суть не в нём. Цвет фона кнопки остаётся неизменным в блокированном состоянии, цвет текста тоже. Но фон изображения меняется на серый. Фон изображения сам по себе - прозрачный. Это позволяет мне легко менять цвет фона кнопок, использовать более интересную цветовую стилизацию всего приложения, чем просто скучно-стандартная.
Можно ли как-то предотвратить "дружескую" помощь tkinter по изменению цвета заблокированных кнопок? Я достаточно долго рылся в документации, ничего не нашёл. Варианта только два:

Отказаться от tkinter вообще. Это не так быстро и отсутствие "эффектов" тоже не гарантировано.
Делать серой всю кнопку. Во-первых, почему только в пользу серого цвета? А если завтра по умолчанию "засеривание" превратится в "засинивание"? Да и "зесеривание" в контексте стилизации цветов в моих приложениях выглядит, мягко говоря, уродливо.

Я не рассчитываю, что решение есть, но на всякий случай... Вдруг я что-то упустил.
ttk, стили ttk - уже пробовал, ноль.

Fox Fox, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Это серьёзно? Вы никогда не видели как для объектов устанавливается свойство state? Тут не о чем писать примеры! Условие и есть пример. Есть кнопка в форме, связанная с процедурой. Когда длительная процедура выполняется, я делаю кнопку недоступной: mybutton.configure(state = "disabled"). По завершении процедуры кнопка становится доступной: mybutton.configure(state = "normal"). Мне не нравится неуправляемое изменение цвета фона изображения. Он становится серым, смотрится противно и этим нельзя управлять. Остальное устраивает. Есть только эта проблема! Никаких других тут нет и быть не может.

Fox Fox, да, то что я пишу - всегда серьезно. Я многое чего видел и слышал и просто хотел помочь вам, но вам это вижу что не очень то и надо.

Решение, компактное и простое, хотя и обходное, я нашёл сам. Tkinter и ttk не написаны как следует и уже не будут дописаны. Значит, надо обходить проблему.
Итак, в форме есть кнопка, связанная с длительной процедурой:
mybutton.configure(command = lambda: mylongprocedure())

Раньше проблема решалась так. Для того, чтоб пользователь не нажал ещё раз на эту же кнопку во время выполнения, кнопку приходилось блокировать:
def mylongprocedure:
# Блокирую кнопку
 mybutton.configure(state = "disabled")
.......................
Код процедуры. Кнопка заблокирована, изображение на ней "засерено". Именно это и не нравится.
.......................
# Деблокирую кнопку
 mybutton.configure(state = "normal")

Теперь проблема будет решаться так:
def mylongprocedure:
# Запоминаю связь кнопки с этой процедурой
 v_command = mybutton.cget("command")
# Обнуляю связь кнопки с этой процедурой
 mybutton.configure(command = "")
.......................
Код процедуры. Кнопка не заблокирована, но нажатие на неё не вызывает параллельное выполнение этой процедуры. Необходимости в блокировке кнопки нет, а значит и фон изображения не меняется.
.......................
# Восстанавливаю связь кнопки с этой процедурой
 mybutton.configure(command = v_command)


Как понимаю, проблема такая:

Тогда предлагаю унаследоваться от tk.Button и просто закостомить свою кнопку:

Через kwargs.pop('command', None) - вырезать заданную функцию для
дальнейшего её вызова.
Через self.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click) - перебиндить на
внутренний метод, тем самым перехватывать событие нажатия.
В методе  on_click в зависимости от флага уже решать блокировать
событие или вызывать его.

import tkinter as tk

class CustomButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, normal_image=None, disabled_image=None, **kwargs):
        self.normal_image = normal_image
        self.disabled_image = disabled_image
        self.is_disabled = False
        self.command = kwargs.pop('command', None)
        super().__init__(master, image=self.normal_image, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)

    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.is_disabled:
            return "break"  # Блок события при заблокированной кнопке
        # Вызов привязанной функции
        if self.command:
            self.command()

    def disable(self):
        self.is_disabled = True
        self.config(image=self.disabled_image)

    def enable(self):
        self.is_disabled = False
        self.config(image=self.normal_image)

root = tk.Tk()

normal_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\K_Enter.png")
disabled_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\K_Enter2.png")

def on_button_click():
    print("Button clicked!")

custom_button = CustomButton(root, normal_image=normal_image, disabled_image=disabled_image, command=on_button_click)
custom_button.pack()

def disable_button():
    custom_button.disable()

def enable_button():
    custom_button.enable()

button_disable = tk.Button(root, text="Disable Button", command=disable_button)
button_disable.pack()

button_enable = tk.Button(root, text="Enable Button", command=enable_button)
button_enable.pack()

root.mainloop()




Дополнительный пример для наглядности:
import tkinter as tk

class CustomButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, normal_image=None, disabled_image=None, **kwargs):
        self.normal_image = normal_image
        self.disabled_image = disabled_image
        self.is_disabled = False
        self.command = kwargs.pop('command', None)
        super().__init__(master, image=self.normal_image, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)

    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.is_disabled:
            return "break"  # Блок события при заблокированной кнопке
        # Вызов привязанной функции
        if self.command:
            self.command()

    def disable(self):
        self.is_disabled = True
        self.config(image=self.disabled_image)

    def enable(self):
        self.is_disabled = False
        self.config(image=self.normal_image)

root = tk.Tk()

normal_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\K_Enter.png")
disabled_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\K_Enter2.png")

def click_button1():
    button1.disable()
    print("Button1 clicked!")
    root.after(4000, button1.enable)
    
def click_button2():
    button2.disable()
    print("Button2 clicked!")
    root.after(4000, button2.enable)
    
def click_button3():
    button3.disable()
    print("Button3 clicked!")
    root.after(4000, button3.enable)

button1 = CustomButton(root, normal_image=normal_image, disabled_image=disabled_image, command=click_button1)
button1.pack()

button2 = CustomButton(root, normal_image=normal_image, disabled_image=disabled_image, command=click_button2)
button2.pack()

button3 = CustomButton(root, normal_image=normal_image, disabled_image=disabled_image, command=click_button3)
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()



Спасибо, конечно. Но я не понимаю вот так написанное вот таким языком идеологически. У меня только в одном несчастном окне обычного приложения 20 кнопок. Вот эту простыню для каждой выписывать?
Я уточню свои вопросы. Мне НУЖНО блокировать кнопки, причём все 20 в одном окне, когда выполняется некая процедура с помощью нажатия какой-то из них. Я вижу в Вашем коде два изображения для одной кнопки? У меня в этом приложении таких кнопок 44! Ваш код я тоже попробовать не могу - из-за непонятных мне изображений.
Нет, мне нужно простое и главное понятное решение.

Лайкнуть, Amgarak, увы, не могу - статусом не вышел. Но спасибо за труды, по-своему идеи были полезными.

В стартовом условии была кнопка и изображение на ней. Предложенное решение порождает два изображения и три кнопки?
Пока вижу, что нормального решения проблемы "дружеской" услуги по изменению цвета нет. В начала я показывал, что решал проблему блокировки двумя строками: в начале mybutton.configure(state = "disabled"), в конце mybutton.configure(state = "normal"). Когда буду посвободнее, попробую аналогичный вариант, но для опции command. То есть, в начале процедуры отменю назначение для кнопки, а в конце восстановлю его. Тогда не придётся блокировать кнопку.

Кстати, а кто будет спасать от "засеривания" две дополнительные кнопки и блокировать их? Ещё 4 кнопки? Без изображений и "защиты"? Нет, куда проще просто забыть о проблеме, сделать кнопки в приложениях серыми или отказаться от tkinter в надежде, что в других средах попустит.
Это еще не самая страшная проблема. Куда неприятнее поведение "крестика" самой формы в процессе выполнения длительной процедуры. На этом сайте есть и такой вопрос от меня. Тоже ноль решений пока что.

@FoxFox добавил ещё один пример.

Спасибо, но я уже написал выше. Это не решение. Это кувалда, которой предлагается колоть орехи. Попробуйте ещё раз почитать мой ответ, он достаточно большой. Мне реальную программу надо писать, а не упражнения с тремя кнопками в форме, две из которых обслуживают третью. :-))))

Я попробовал с утра предложенное мною же выше решение. Допустим, что:
mybutton.configure(command = lambda: my_long_procedure())
В процедуре my_long_procedure(), в начале я пишу:
mybutton.configure(command = "")
А в конце восстанавливаю:
mybutton.configure(command = lambda: my_long_procedure())
Я ещё не протестировал глубоко, но работает. Нажатие на кнопку в процессе не мешает. Кнопку переводить в режим disabled не нужно. Это две срочки кода! Никаких двух кнопок в придачу и дополнительных изображений! Никаких простыней для 44 кнопок! Правда, остальные кнопки в форме доступны...

Ну и наконец можно сделать и более профессионально внутри процедуры my_long_procedure():
В начале:
mycommand = mybutton.cget('command')
mybutton.configure(command = "")
В конце:
mybutton.configure(command = mycommand)
С цветом проблема не решается, так хоть таким костылём можно обойти. С минимальными усилиями.

@FoxFox Почему кувалда? Нормальная практика унаследоваться от класса и немного его подправить до нужной логики. К тому же во втором примере я вам наглядно показал, что включение и отключение кнопки нормально работает внутри для конкретной кнопки(не нужны доп кнопки для включение и отключения другой кнопки).

Вы читаете мои ответы? Я уже решил проблему тремя строчками! Без классов, без трёх кнопок и двух изображений. Я лайкнул Вам. За труды. Но принцип бритвы Оккама у нас, математиков, в чести, а именно: не вводить сущностей без необходимости. Если я вот так буду решать вот такие проблемы, мне лучше не стоит заниматься программированием вообще.

@FoxFox смотрите, я вам предлагаю сделать один раз класс и далее использовать удобный интерфейс для работы с блокированием кнопок. Вы же для каждой кнопки будете городить 3 строчки кода которые будут запутывать ваш код.

Ну, я не буду повторяться... Не подходит. В реальных приложениях я уже использую класс для создания кнопок. Это всё Ваше туда не засунуть нормально. Я всё, что думаю об этом решении, уже написал. Это не решение. Спасибо.

@FoxFox опубликуйте своё решение в виде ответа на свой же вопрос, возможно это кому-то так же пригодится.
